# How to recalculate DataFrame column values based on condition dict (Pandas Python)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have the following DataFrame:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | aa | 4.32 |
| 1 | aa | 7.00 |
| 2 | bb | 8.00 |
| 3 | dd | 74.00 |
| 4 | cc | 30.00 |
| 5 | bb | 2.00 |

And let's say I have the following dict which determs the condition for column A in its keys and determs the multiplier for coulmn B in its values:

```
dict1={'aa':-1, 'bb':2}
```

All I want is to multiply values in column B with vulues from dict1 based on condition that values in column A are queal to dict1 keys.

So the ouptput should be:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | aa | -4.32 |
| 1 | aa | -7.00 |
| 2 | bb | 16.00 |
| 3 | dd | 74.00 |
| 4 | cc | 30.00 |
| 5 | bb | 4.00 |

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.Series.map`:

```
print (df["A"].map(dict1).fillna(1)*df["B"])

0    -4.32
1    -7.00
2    16.00
3    74.00
4    30.00
5     4.00
dtype: float64
```